# undefined method `comment_url' for #<CommentsController:0x00007fb775ff20d8>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am following a tutorial on youtube and trying to set comments on posts without page refresh. I have this setup in .js file. But in route redirect I got this error -
CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
 def create
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = @article.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
   @comment.name = current_user.email
   respond_to do |format|
     if @comment.save
       format.js 
       format.html { redirect_to @comment }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
     else
     end
   end
 end

 def destroy
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
   @comment.destroy
   redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

   get 'search/index'

   devise_for :users
   get 'welcome/index'
   get '/search', to: 'search#search'

   resources :user
   resources :articles do
     resources :comments
     member do
       put "like" => "articles#like"
       put "unlike" => "articles#unlike"
      end
    end
   resources :search, only: [:index]

   root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org             /routing.html
 end
```

Error -

```
     NoMethodError (undefined method `comment_url' for                                                           #<CommentsController:0x00007fb775ff20d8>):

     app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in create'
     app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

create.js.erb file

```
   $('#forma2 table').append("<%= j render @comment %>")
```

Comment: Your indentation is just chaos. You may want to check the `resource :articles do` but have no corresponding `end`

Comment: I am suggesting to read about how this `*_url` are created then you will be able to solved your issue. If you look here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html at point 2.7 there is good explanation why you do not have `comment_url`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have nested routes: users > comments therefore you can't `redirect_to @comment`this way.

Your create action would need something like:

```
if @comment.save
  format.js 
  format.html { redirect_to user_comments_path(current_user, @comment) }
  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }
else
  format.html { render :new }
  format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

Please check your routes by issuing this at your command line: 
`bundle exec rake routes`

Also have a look to [nested resources and routes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) on the official guides.

Comment: I will try in 2 hours, can you maybe tell me, whar I need to write in else in the same code, mine else is empty. And when i to validations and try, that cause me error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error occurred in this line.

`format.html { redirect_to @comment }`

Make sure you're posting your request to `create.js` not `create.html`

Comment: Hmm maybe? Can you type me a line of code that I need to paste over mine?

Comment: Can you post your code that makes the request to `comments#create` ?